# Why always TECH_DISCOVERED or TAG_DISCOVERED but not NDEF_DISCOVERED?

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter, ndef

I am just new to NFC in Android. I have a few questions on it. First, let me introduce the code. In my program, it just simply retrieves the payload from the records and log them as strings.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    nfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),  0);
    nfcFilter = new IntentFilter[]{
                new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED),
                new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED),
                new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)
            };
    techList = new String[][]{{Ndef.class.getName()}};
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    if (adapter != null){
        adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, nfcFilter, techList);
        if (!adapter.isEnabled()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "please enable your nfc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "your device do not have nfc.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if (adapter != null){
        adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    String TAG = "onNewIntent";
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Log.d(TAG, "action: "+intent.getAction());
    //Log.d(TAG, "type: "+intent.getType());
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
        Parcelable[] rawMsg = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMsg != null){
            for (int i=0; i<rawMsg.length; i++){
                NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage)rawMsg[i];
                NdefRecord[] records = msg.getRecords();
                for (int j=0; j<records.length; j++){
                    Log.d(TAG, records[j].toMimeType()+"");
                    byte [] payload = records[j].getPayload();
                    if (payload != null && payload.length > 0){
                        Log.d(TAG, new String(payload, 1, payload.length-1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){

    } else if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
        Parcelable[] rawMsg = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMsg != null){
            for (int i=0; i<rawMsg.length; i++){
                NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage)rawMsg[i];
                NdefRecord[] records = msg.getRecords();
                for (int j=0; j<records.length; j++){
                    Log.d(TAG, records[j].toMimeType()+"");
                    byte [] payload = records[j].getPayload();
                    if (payload != null && payload.length > 0){
                        Log.d(TAG, new String(payload, 1, payload.length-1)+"("+j+")");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, it comes two questions:

1. The result tells the foreground dispatcher only catch TECH_DISCOVERED(with techList) and TAG_DISCOVERED(without techList) but miss the NDEF_DISCOVERED.
2. When I leave the app and scan the NFC tag, it automatically brings me to the website(I put a url as a record). How it tells this record consist an action to open a browser or make a call?

Comment: Why I can't trigger a NDEF_DISCOVERED action???

Answer (score 4):

The `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter will typically (some exceptions seem to exist) only match if it has a an associated data type that matches the NDEF message on the tag. So for instance, the data type specification `*/*` will match any MIME type:

```
IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
try {
    ndef.addDataType("*/*");
} catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {}
nfcFilter = new IntentFilter[]{
        ndef,
        new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED),
        new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)
};
```

Similarly, if you only want to trigger for a specific URL http://www.example.com/, you could use:

```
IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
ndef.addDataScheme("http");
ndef.addDataAuthority("www.example.com", null);
```

---

**Note** that -- with the foreground dispatch system -- you would typically only register the most generic intent filter that you want to match. Thus, if your foreground dispatch intent filter already contains the action `TAG_DISCOVERED`, there is no need to add any more specific filters (like `TECH_DISCOVERED` or `NDEF_DISCOVERED`), as your activity will already receive any discovered tag. The same applies for `TECH_DISCOVERED` in combination with `Ndef` tag technology: This already contains any tag that would trigger `NDEF_DISCOVERED`. However, note that the `TAG_DISCOVERED` intent filter is special in that it means "catch-all" when used with the foreground dispatch while it means "fallback-only" (i.e. only match if there is no better match with any other app) when used in manifest-based intent filters.

Comment: I add the data type but still it is not a NDEF_DISCOVERED action. If I use TAG_DISCOVERED instead, can the message be similarly retrieved? Does all message follows the NDEF format?

Comment: @Simon What NDEF message do you have on your tag? If you receive the `TAG_DISCOVERED` intent action for the combination of all three intent filters (like above), your tag does not contain any NDEF message/is not detected as NDEF tag.

Comment: I have 2 text/plain records and the tag supports ndef, nfca, ultralight technology......how to know the tag has NDEF message or not? or detected as NDEF? The structure does follow NDEF message as what I do in the code runs so well

Comment: You can check with some of the available tag inspection tools (e.g. my [NFC TagInfo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo)).